# test case for a react component method with jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I am new to unit testing. I have a react component

```js
export default class Login extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      email: '',
      password:'',
      validFields: false
    }
    
    this.handleChangeInput = this.handleChangeInput.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChangeInput(e){
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
    if (this.state.email.length>0 &&         this.state.password.length>0 ) {
      this.setState({validFields: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({validFields: false});
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLoginSubmit}>
          <div className="input">
            <input id="email" type="text" name ="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChangeInput}/>
          </div>
          <div className="input">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangeInput}/>
          </div>
          <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value ="LOG IN" disabled={!this.state.validFields}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now I want to test the function handleChangeInput(e). Can anyone help to simulate the test case for the function ? I am using jest and enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method makes 2 setState call, which is suboptimal.

To test it in a jest test case, you can follow this guideline (read the jest doc to have an idea how to write better tests https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html):

```
describe('<Login>', () => {

    describe('handleChangeInput', () => {

        const component = new Login()

        beforeEach(() => {
            component.setState = jest.fn()
        })

        test('calls setState validFields false when no email/password', () => {
            const state = { state : { email: '', password: ''} }
            const args = { target : { name: 'name', value: 'value' } }
            component.handleChangeInput.call(state, args)
            expect(component.setState.mock.calls.length).toBe(2)
            expect(component.setState.mock.calls[1][0]).toEqual({validFields:false})
        })

        test('calls setState validFields true when email/password are ok', () => {
            const state = { state : { email: 'email', password: 'password' } }
            const args = { target : { name: 'name', value: 'value' } }
            component.handleChangeInput.call(state, args)
            expect(component.setState.mock.calls.length).toBe(2)
            expect(component.setState.mock.calls[1][0]).toEqual({validFields:true})
        })
})
```

(code not tested)

Comment: I have changed the function in the react component to this  
handleChangeInput(e){
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value},()=>{
      this.checkFields();
    });
  }

  checkFields(){
    if (this.state.email.length>0 && this.state.password.length>0 ) {
      this.setState({validFields: true});
    }else {
      this.setState({validFields: false});
    }
  } But the return value of the test function is {"name": "value"} instead of {"validFields": false}